# How to determine maximal error correction/detection method for 6 + 1 digits?

Tags: algorithm, error-correction

I have the following constraints for a number that will be recognized from an image:

- 6 digits data
- 1 digit error correction
- The first 6 digits cannot be changed (they must be human readable)
- The check digit must remain a numeral

The error correction scheme currently is based on a checksum, such that the 7th digit is the last digit of the sum of the first 6 digits.

E.g.

```
123456 => 1234561
999999 => 9999994
472912 => 4729125
219274 => 2192745
```

How can I determine the number and types of errors this scheme can detect/correct, and is there a scheme that will provide better error detection?  (Error detection is more important than error correction for my use case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Luhn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), it's a little more complex that what you describe but it will meet your requirements.

A copy paste from wikipedia:

> The Luhn algorithm will detect any single-digit error, as well as
> almost all transpositions of adjacent digits. It will not, however,
> detect transposition of the two-digit sequence 09 to 90 (or vice
> versa). It will detect 7 of the 10 possible twin errors (it will not
> detect 22 ↔ 55, 33 ↔ 66 or 44 ↔ 77).
>
> Other, more complex check-digit
> algorithms (such as the Verhoeff algorithm and the Damm algorithm) can
> detect more transcription errors. The Luhn mod N algorithm is an
> extension that supports non-numerical strings.
>
> Because the algorithm
> operates on the digits in a right-to-left manner and zero digits
> affect the result only if they cause shift in position, zero-padding
> the beginning of a string of numbers does not affect the calculation.
> Therefore, systems that pad to a specific number of digits (by
> converting 1234 to 0001234 for instance) can perform Luhn validation
> before or after the padding and achieve the same result.
>
> Prepending a
> 0 to odd-length numbers enables you to process the number from left to
> right rather than right to left, doubling the odd-place digits.
>
> The
> algorithm appeared in a US Patent for a hand-held, mechanical device
> for computing the checksum. It was therefore required to be rather
> simple. The device took the mod 10 sum by mechanical means. The
> substitution digits, that is, the results of the double and reduce
> procedure, were not produced mechanically. Rather, the digits were
> marked in their permuted order on the body of the machine.